# How to create a single Calendar object with a Date object and a string that holds the time. - JAVA

Tags: string, date

I am currently trying to make a Calendar object. One function returns a Date object which holds the Month, Day and year. And another function returns a string object holding the time.

How do I use both of this information to create a single Calendar object?

I am using Java

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calender;
import java.util.Date;

public class Test {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main (String args[]) {

    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        Date date = sdf.parse("2011-03-17");
        // suppose your method return date object like prior line date object.

        //now you get time from a method which returns date String like time below: 
        String time = "23:44:33";
        String splitTime[] = time.split(":");

        // Now create a single CAlender object containing time and date

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, date.getDate());
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, date.getMonth());
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, date.getYear());
        // till this point we have set the date

        // now we will set the time
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, Integer.parseInt(splitTime[0]));
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(splitTime[1]));
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, Integer.parseInt(splitTime[2]));

        System.out.println(sdf1.format(calendar.getTime()));

        //You will get the desired result
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

But 
Fetching day, month, year from date obbject is Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR/MONTH/DAY). Refer Java Doc for more information.

For year we need to add 1900 in year what we get from d.getYear(). Because it provides year - 1900. Still, deprecated code shouldn't be used. Use Calender class only.

Hope you got your answer !!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use old troublesome date-time classes, now legacy. Use java.time classes.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.MAY , 23 );
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 12 , 23 , 45 );
```

To generate a String representing either value in standard ISO 8601 format, call `toString`. For other formats use, `DateTimeFormatter`.

Please search Stack Overflow before posting. This has been handled hundreds of times already.